# how to type an object that contains a indeterminate amount of a specific object

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I need to type the parameter of an NgRx action. This parameter is an object that contains an indeterminate number of specific object. This last object is already type on a Interface.

```
export interface CustomDistribution {
    maxWindowsActive: number,
    resize: boolean,
}
```

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
export const updateCustomDistributions = createAction(
  '[Custom Distributions] update Custom Distributions',
  props<{ customDistributions: CustomDistribution{} }>(),
);
```

This is an example of the expected object I want to get and type:

```
   distributions: { 
      right: {  
        maxWindowsActive: 1;
        resize: true
      },
      left: {  
        maxWindowsActive: 2;
        resize: false
      }
    }
```

Comment: your result type is invalid javascript. Please update. Also, how should we get that  `maxWindowsActive` should be 1 or 2?

Comment: What you mean by invalid javascript. The above code is typescript. The property maxWindowsActive can accept any positive and interger number

Comment: Your expected example isn't a valid object

Comment: Why? Its an object with two object of the same type inside

Comment: there is no key for the inner objects. how that is a valid typescript/javascript?

Comment: @Jmainol objects are key/value pairs. More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: Your are both right. I already corrected the expected object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is most likely this:

```typescript
export interface CustomDistributionGroup {
  [key: string]: CustomDistribution
  // or like that, if you want to allow numeric keys
  // [key: number]: CustomDistribution
  // [key: string | number]: CustomDistribution // both string and number
  // thanks @Brandon Taylor
}
```

If you define an interface like that, then you can use it to create an object with indefinite number of `CustomDistribution` objects. **But they need a key**, which you didn't provide in your example => an invalid object.
This is how it should look:

```
const someProps: CustomDistributionGroup {
  first: { maxWindowsActive: 1; resize: true },
  second: { maxWindowsActive: 2; resize: false },
  third: { maxWindowsActive: 3; resize: false },
  // and so one
}
```

Your example should not work and I'm surprised your IDE is not throwing errors.

Comment: @Jmainol keep in mind that object keys can be numbers, so `{ 0: { ... } }` will also work if you don't want to define a string-based key.

Comment: you're welcome. The O.P. might just want an array of CustomDistribution objects. Difficult to tell from their question.

Comment: maybe it's my lack of understanding of typescript. But I thought that just as string[] is valid, customDistribution{} could also be.